# Firestore: How to order results by not filtered field?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I saw the Firestore documentation and I need exactly a feature, that is not possible.
I want to filter comments from a specific user and want to order his comments by date.

Like below (which is invalid according to Firestore):

```
docRef
    .whereField("user", isEqualTo: "John Doe")
    .order(by: "date")
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Why would this not be possible? Did you try the query? Was there an error message?

Comment: Yes, the result is empty. It is explicitly mentioned that it`s invalid here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: When that happens, always check the log output for warnings/errors. But aside from that, can you show a (screenshot of a) document that you'd expect back fro this query. It'd also help to see how you're executing the query, and for example logging that it has 0 results.

Comment: I checked the logs and found the solution. It says `UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/[...]` I created the Index. But the documentation was confusing for not mentioned that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Index before you sort by another field than filtered.
Go to Cloud Firestore -> Indexes to create it or follow the link provided in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore order and filter in multiple fields within these [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations). The combination you're showing in your code does not hit those limitations as far as I can see, so it should be possible. Most likely you're just missing the necessary index.

If you want to filter/order on multiple fields, you'll need to define an index on that combination of fields. When the necessary index is missing, the output of your app will contain a message to that effect, which contains a direct link that you can click to create the index **with all necessary fields prepopulated**. So check the log output of your app for such a message whenever you're not getting the results you expect.